# [404]can't go from doGet() to doPost() (at board_write)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

[image]

I'd like to connect to 'boardWrite.jsp' 
when clicking that colored (write) button. (using command)
other functions are doing well but only this is going wrong.

error message is 404 like this

[image]

when I tried Debugging, I found that it can't go from `doGet()` to `doPost()` at BoardServlet.java below.

Here's my code...

Since I am a newbie, my question looks absurd i know.
But it is important for me now..then..I hope I can get a help here.
I am doing my best..

```
 ***1. boardlist.jsp***

    `<body>
      <div id="wrap" align="center">
        <h1>게시글 리스트</h1>
        <table class="list">
          <tr>
            <td colspan=5 style="border:white; text-align:right">
              <a href = "BoardServlet?command=board_write_form">게시글등록</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>번호</th>
            <th>제목</th>
            <th>작성자</th>
            <th>작성일</th>
            <th>조회</th>

          </tr>


            <c:forEach var="board" items="${boardList}"> 
           <tr class = "record">
             <td>${board.num}</td>
             <td><a href="BoardServlet?command=board_view&num=${board.num}">${board.title}</a></td>
             <td>${board.name}</td>
             <td><fmt:formatDate value="${board.writedate}" /></td>
             <td>${board.readcount}</td>
           </tr> 


            </c:forEach>

        </table>


      </div>`

    2. BoardServlet.java 
package com.board.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.board.controller.action.Action;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class BoardServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/BoardServlet")
public class BoardServlet extends HttpServlet {     //컨트롤러 클래스
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public BoardServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String command = request.getParameter("command");
        System.out.println("BoardServlet에서 요청을 받음을 확인 :"+command);
        ActionFactory af = ActionFactory.getInstance();
        Action action = af.getAction(command);
        if(action!=null){
            action.execute(request, response);

        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}


    ***2.ActionFactory.java***

    `package com.board.controller;

    import com.board.controller.action.Action;
    import com.board.controller.action.BoardListAction;
    import com.board.controller.action.BoardViewAction;
    import com.board.controller.action.BoardWriteAction;
    import com.board.controller.action.BoardWriteFormAction;

    public class ActionFactory {
        private static ActionFactory instance = new ActionFactory();

        private ActionFactory(){
            super();
        }

        public static ActionFactory getInstance(){
            return instance; 
        }

        // 요청된 명령어별로 분기 처리하는 메서드 

        public Action getAction(String command){
            Action action = null;
            System.out.println("ActionFactory:"+command);

            if(command.equals("board_list")){
                action = new BoardListAction();  // 객체를 생성했다는 말은 => 해당 객체의 클래스를 찾아간다는 의미로 받아들여도 된다.
            }else if(command.equals("board_view")){
                action = new BoardViewAction();
            }else if(command.equals("board_write_form")){
                action = new BoardWriteFormAction();
            }else if(command.equals("board_write")){
                action = new BoardWriteAction();
            }
            return action;
        }

    }`

    3. BoardDAO.java

       ' public class BoardDAO {

        private BoardDAO(){}

        private static BoardDAO instance = new BoardDAO();

        public static BoardDAO getInstance(){
            return instance;
        }

        public List<BoardVO> selectAllBoard(){
            String sql = "select * from board order by num desc";
            List<BoardVO> list = new ArrayList<BoardVO>();
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null; 
            ResultSet rs = null; 

            try{
                conn=DBManager.getConnection();
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                while(rs.next()){
                    BoardVO bVo = new BoardVO();
                    bVo.setNum(rs.getInt("num"));
                    bVo.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                    bVo.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                    bVo.setPass(rs.getString("pass"));
                    bVo.setContent(rs.getString("content"));
                    bVo.setReadcount(rs.getInt("readcount"));
                    bVo.setWritedate(rs.getTimestamp("writedate"));
                    list.add(bVo);
                }

            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                DBManager.close(rs, stmt, conn);
            }

            return list;
        } 

        // 글 내용의 readcount 값 증가 

        public void updateReadCount(String num){
            String sql = "update board set readcount=readcount+1 where num=?";
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 

            try{
                conn = DBManager.getConnection();
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstmt.setString(1, num);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();


            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                DBManager.close(pstmt, conn);
            }
        }

        // 게시판 글 상세 내용 보기 

        public BoardVO selectBoardByNum(String num){
            String sql = "select * from board where num=?";
            BoardVO bVo = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            try{ 
                 conn = DBManager.getConnection();
                 pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                 pstmt.setString(1, num);
                 rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                 if(rs.next()){
                     bVo = new BoardVO();

                     bVo.setNum(rs.getInt("num"));
                     bVo.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                     bVo.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                     bVo.setPass(rs.getString("pass"));
                     bVo.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                     bVo.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                     bVo.setContent(rs.getString("content")); 
                     bVo.setWritedate(rs.getTimestamp("writedate"));
                     bVo.setReadcount(rs.getInt("readCount"));
                 }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                DBManager.close(rs, pstmt, conn);
            }
            return bVo;
        }

        //게시글 등록 
        public void insertBoard(BoardVO bVo){
            String sql = "insert into board("
                    + "num, name, email, pass, title, content )"
                    + "values(board_seq.nextVal, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

            try{
                conn = DBManager.getConnection();
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                pstmt.setString(1, bVo.getName());
                pstmt.setString(2, bVo.getEmail());
                pstmt.setString(3, bVo.getPass());
                pstmt.setString(4, bVo.getTitle());
                pstmt.setString(5, bVo.getContent());
                pstmt.executeUpdate();

            }catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                DBManager.close(pstmt, conn);
            }
        }


    }'

    ***4. BoardWriteFormAction.java***

    public class BoardWriteFormAction implements Action {

        @Override
        public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String url = "\board\boardWrite.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
```

Comment: looks like you have not deployed this jsp correctly, because the error is mentions `%08oard%08oardWrite.jsp` which is nothing to do with this `BoardServlet`

Answer (score -1):

Since you are getting a 404 error, I suspect that your servlet is not correctly mapped in your web.xml. Check that. If you do not know what this means, then Google how to set up a web.xml for a servlet or JSP application on Tomcat. In short, this is what maps a request URL to your servlet class. If you haven't done this, then the server doesn't know what "BoardServlet" is.

Also, you do not say, but is your log statement via System.out.printl in the doGet method of your servlet printing output to the Catalina console? If it is, then you know your servlet is being called. If not, then I again suggest you make sure your servlet is correctly mapped in your web.xml.

Lastly, you should use java.util.logging (or another logging solution) to log code on your server. While System.out.printl will work in Tomcat and write to the console, that won't work when your server is not your development machine.

Comment: thank you for your sincere comments. i'm still working on it